# Image not changing for different size classes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am just starting out with Swift and I'm following a tutorial which involves importing two images, one for compact width, any height, and one for any width, any height, but both with the same reference. In the tutorial after he has imported the images and set them up for different size classes, he drags the image into storyboard and it automatically adapts to the current size class.

Mine doesn't, it always uses the any width, any height image. In the simulator it uses the correct image but it is still annoying as I have to use trial and error with the constraints since I have the larger image in storyboard which has a different aspect ratio.

Any solutions? If you need more info or I haven't made much sense, please ask.

Cheers

Comment: I think it depends on the size class you are currently using, What is your currently size class??

Comment: I am in compact width, regular height